# Fixed effects in OLS

Tags: r, effects

I am new to `R`, so I apologize in advance if the question may sound inappropriate.

I have a sample of 484 M&A deals (each deal is unique) and I ran a regression to understand if multiples paid for companies with a specific characteristic differ from those paid for targets that do not have it.
After reviewing the literature regarding the topic, I included some control variables, but I don't understand the following: in previous papers, authors running a similar regression to the one I'm currently working on included fixed effects for "Entry Year", "Country" and "Industry" of the M&A targets. However, after looking for R codes/packages suggestions on how to do this, it seems to me that fixed effects are always used in panel data and not in samples like the one I have, where each deal is unique and I don't have N observations of the same individual over time.

How do I include fixed effects in R in the regression I'm trying to run? Is there a way to do so or am I missing some information? Maybe authors of the research papers I read are using the terminology "fixed effects" referring to some other treatment?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your dataset, you have 484 observations (rows). These observations are structured in a way such that there is:

- at least one categorical variable such as `ID_doer` which is a name of someone doing something
- at least a factor (ordinal) variable as `exposure`, which is the feature that some doers have and others have not (or, they have it on different levels of exposure).
- an `outcome` variable which is your dependent variable

If this is the case, given the formula

`outcome ~ exposure + ID_doer`

you can look at the relationship between the `exposure` feature and your `outcome` feature, de-biasing the `estimate` of the concept express in `exposure` from the hidden, circumstantial, features fixed in the identity of who is doing stuff in your dataset.

This formula would work for regressions in the `stats` package but not for other packages like `plm` or `lme4`. Anyway, those are still quite intuitive; I think they require proper panel data to work, too.

Basically you only have a hierarchical categorical variable, so you could be interested to further investigate hierarchical/multilevel models depends by the structure of your database.

I would discourage to adopt fixed effects ("within estimation") if the average of observations per `ID_doer` is not sufficiently high, i.e. if there are more than 150 unique `ID_doer` in your dataset of 484 observations.